# Steam Trade Bot on java

Tags: java, steam-web-api, steam

Здравствуйте!

Подскажите как реализовать steam trade bot на java, который будет обмениваться вещами с клиентами на сайте? Посоветуйте какую библиотеку использовать?

Читал доки steam web api и насколько понял что надо использовать технологию openid. но на этом осознания решения задачи заканчиваются) возможно я что то упускаю...

Нашел решения на php, js, c# но по java  нашел только устаревшие реализации которые не работают.

Answer (score 4):

Есть Java обертка над С++ API для Steam - [SteamWorks4J](https://github.com/code-disaster/steamworks4j)

Автор говорит, что не все функции API работают, но обещает добавлять, если подвешивать ему *issue*

Comment: Спасибо большое за ваш ответ @barmaley . Буду разбираться!

Comment: Но вопрос по прежнему открыт для других ответов) Возможно кто то может предложить подробное описание решения проблемы)

Comment: API есть дальше уже сами. Будут конкретные вопросы - обращайтесь

Answer (score 0):

[Java Steam Trade Library](https://github.com/wonderf/steam-trade-library)

Написал библиотеку для отправки и принятия обменов